# Insert new records using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How to insert record to database using linq and c#?

my function looks like this:

```
private void submitEntry(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        using ( var ctx = new ServiceDataContext()) {
            try {
                String selection1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                String[] spl1 = selection1.Split(' ');
                var cond1 = spl1[ 0 ];
                var cond2 = spl1[ 1 ];
                var query1 = (from p in ctx.products where p.brand == cond1 && p.model == cond2 select p.prodId).FirstOrDefault();

                String selection5 = comboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString();
                String[] spl5 = selection5.Split(',',' ');
                var cond1_5 = spl5[ 0 ];
                var cond2_5 = spl5[ 2 ];
                var query5 = (from c in ctx.contactPersons where c.lastName == cond1_5 && c.firstName == cond2_5 select c.contId).FirstOrDefault();

                var query4 = (from h in ctx.hospitals where h.name == comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() select h.hospId).FirstOrDefault();

                mainWindow mainClass = new mainWindow();

                MessageBox.Show(mainClass.logId.ToString());

                entry ent = new entry { prodId = Convert.ToInt32(query1),
                                        prodQty = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text),
                                        hospId = Convert.ToInt32(query4),
                                        contId = Convert.ToInt32(query5),
                                        freqMaintenance = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),
                                        empId = Convert.ToInt32(emp)
                                      };
                ctx.entries.InsertOnSubmit(ent);
                ctx.SubmitChanges();
            } catch {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR 404: Database Not Found");
            }
        }
    }
```

its throwing me this exception: `Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.Linq.dll`

i tried to test it by adding `MessageBox.Show("1");` and it seems to stop apearing after `ctx.SubmitChanges();`

Comment: Where does it throw this error? What does "it seems to stop apearing after" mean?

Comment: create a string variable outside the linq query4  for comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() and replace with that variable.
var value = comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString();
var query4 = (from h in ctx.hospitals where h.name == value select h.hospId).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wonder why it is valid for you

ctx.**entries**.InsertOnSubmit(ent);

when your model is **entry**

```
entry ent = new entry { prodId = Convert.ToInt32(query1),
                                            prodQty = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text),
                                            hospId = Convert.ToInt32(query4),
                                            contId = Convert.ToInt32(query5),
                                            freqMaintenance = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),
                                            empId = Convert.ToInt32(emp)
                                          };
```

as i know the linq syntax do not handle plural.

in fact i am expecting something like

```
ctx.entry.InsertOnSubmit(ent);
```

otherwise post out your dbcontext code may help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SqlException, you have to debug sql statement, for this log sql

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    SqlError err = ex.Errors[0];
    string message = string.Empty;
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", message);
}
```